# How to update WordPress dockerfile to use PHP 8?

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile, php-8

I am using a docker image to build a WordPress site on Amazon Web Services, and it is currently using WordPress 6.0 but PHP 7.4. I want to update the image so it uses PHP 8.

This is part of the Dockerfile currently -

```
FROM wordpress:6.0
ARG ENV=production

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bash \
    curl \
    python \
    unzip \
  webpack \
  git \
    && cd /tmp \
  && curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle-1.16.188.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip" \
  && unzip awscli-bundle.zip \
  && ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws \
  && rm awscli-bundle.zip \
  && rm -rf awscli-bundle \
  && rm -rf /tmp/src \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I've tried changing it to -

```
FROM wordpress:6.0
FROM php:8.0-apache
ARG ENV=production
```

as well as

```
FROM wordpress:6.0:php:8.0-apache
ARG ENV=production
```

but I get an error when trying to build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
FROM wordpress:6.0
FROM php:8.0-apache
```

Is telling Docker to build your image from two different base images, which makes no sense.

This:

```
FROM wordpress:6.0:php:8.0-apache
```

You are just making up some new Docker image tag syntax, which is not going to work.

You need to look at what base [WordPress docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) are available, and pick one of those available images. For example `wordpress:6.0-php8.0`. You would change your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM wordpress:6.0-php8.0
```